# Overriding LayeredNavigation Block not working

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation"
        type="OSE\ProductVisibility\Rewrite\Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" />
</config>
```

**Navigation.php**

```
<?php
namespace OSE\ProductVisibility\Rewrite\Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block;

class Navigation extends \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
    }
    public function getText()
    {
        echo 'hello';
    }
}
```

**view.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Category layered navigation
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation
 */
echo get_class($block);
$block->getText();

exit();
?>
```

I have this configuration, But when I echo out `get_class($block)` it is pointing to a different block. DO i did it wrong? DO i need to do anything else? Help would be really appreciated

Comment: what is purpose of the  getText() method?

Comment: You can use view Model

Comment: getText is my custom method that i wanted to test if it is calling the correct Block